# Which Analysis and Reporting Web-Based system?

Tags: reporting-services, olap, data-analysis

I need to choose a solution (better if open source) that give to me:

- Report Designer web gui for the end-user, width support for bar/line/scatter/pie charts,
- Web-based Interactive Analysis gui for the end-user (with drill down navigable charts),
- Report Generation Engine with email time-scheduled Report Delivery.

I'm planning to transfer my data to the Analysis and Reporting System by nightly batch.

So what's to choose and to integrate? Am I forced to setup an OLAP Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found interesting [Magic Quadrant for Business Intelligence Platforms](http://www.gartner.com/technology/reprints.do?id=1-196WFCB&ct=120207&st=sb)

Answer (score 0):

1. Report Designer in Visual Studio / BIDS
2. Reporting Services reports published to Report Manager or SharePoint portals, and/or Excel Pivot Tables published to Excel Web Services in SharePoint
3. Reporting Services reports published to Report Manager or SharePoint portals

Transfer data would be Integration Services

Comment: It's important that the report designer is accessible and understandable by the end-user.

Comment: That's an unrealistic goal IMO.  Interactive analysis maybe (within pre-defined reports or OLAP cube), but the task of useful report design is beyond the comprehension of the typical end-user or even power user. I'm not talking about data dumps, but useful, intelligent reports that answer business questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can go for Microsoft SQL Server Business Intelligence Tools.

For reporting you can use Sql Server Reporting Service.
and for data manipulation, analysis, dumping, you can use Sql Server Integration Service.

## Pros:

1. Sql Server Reporting Service (SSRS) is very easy to use reporting service.
2. Seamless integration with ASP.NET, SSIS, SSAS applications.
3. Heavy Data Processing.
4. Limited no. of tools. Hence less complexity. Straight forward approach in making reports
5. SSIS packages can deal with very heavy data dumping or processing such as reading from ftp files, almost millions of rows. backdoor processing.
6. Web Services, APIs can be integrated.
7. Sql Server Analysis Service (SSAS) allows one to make cubes for predicting patterns and heavy data manipulation.
8. Very easy to setup a report server.

## Cons:

1. Expressions in SSRS are not that robust.
2. Export functionality (i.e. export to pdf, excel, csv) is limited.

The best part is very2 easy integration with sql server, asp.net apps.

I also have used Telerik's reporting service.
They are easy to use aswell, but they are abundant with features, so many things can be done through so many ways, hence kind of complex.

It depends, the level of your app's dependence.
I've been successfully delivering projects using MS's BIDS.

sure they are limited, but then easy to use.

Comment: It's important that the report designer is accessible and understandable by the end-user.